# Trying to make a double array, numbered 2 to 50

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, double

I'm trying to make a 5 by 10 table using a double array. The first box should be blank, then the rest numbered 2-50.

I have this so far but it is not working.

```
int array[][] = new int[5][10];
      for(int row=1; row<5;row++){
         for(int col=1;col<10;col++)
            array[row][col] = row*col;}
         System.out.println(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row * col` cannot give you consecutive numbers from `2 to 50`. And in your code, you are not just leaving the `first box`, but you are leaving out `first row` and `first column` completely.

You should run the loop normally from `0 to max`. And for `[0][0]`, don't print anything.

Also, for printing from `2 to 50`, just have a count variable which starts with `2`, and after printing it, increment it by `1`.

Here's the modified code: -

```
int array[][] = new int[5][10];
int count = 2;

for(int row=0; row<5;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<10;col++) {
        if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        array[row][col] = count++;
    }
}
for (int[] inner: array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inner));
}
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

**NOTE: -**

Since you want your `first box` to be blank, you can't use `Arrays.toString` here. You would have to use one more loop, and print your array in simple ways. And when your indices are `[0][0]`, just `sysout("");`

Comment: He requested that the first box be blank, not zero. Therefore you can't use `Arrays.toString`

Comment: @durron597.. Hmm. For that case, he would need to add one more loop. It's just the matter of printing. I'll quote that though. thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to add one more loop, I did it without an extra loop in my code below :) Loop reuse!

Comment: @durron597.. lol ;) More surprising is there is no reply from OP.

Answer (score 1):

The first box can't be blank... it could be zero, is that what you want?

Changes:

1. Use `0` indices, not `1` indices
2. You have to print the contents of the array manually, see where I print a comma below
3. `row * col` isn't the correct value. use `row * 10 + col + 1`

Try this:

```
int array[][] = new int[5][10];
for(int row=0; row<5;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<10;col++) {
        array[row][col] = row * 10 + col + 1;
        if (array[row][col] < 2) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(array[row][col]);
        }
        if (col < 9) System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

Comment: Actually, you need `row * 10 + col + 1` -> `1 extra` is needed, since you have `0-based index`

Comment: @durron597.. I would suggest, change your output according to the change you did in code. Your current output is the one before the change I suggested.